# Incrustar texto plano en opencms

Tags: html5, cms

Estamos intentando cambiar la etiqueta `iframe` en una página. Queremos incrustar un fichero de texto plano pero `Opencms` usa la etiqueta `object` sólo para ficheros multimedia.

Estábamos intentando hacer esto:

```
<object width="910" height="340" type="text/plain" data="https://www.mozilla.org/media/MPL/2.0/index.815ca599c9df.txt" border="0"></object>
```

Gracias

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow en espanol. This site is for questions and answers in Spanish. Please translate your question to Spanish to avoid it being closed. Or, if you want to use English, you can ask it on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) instead.